# Postgres query shows under the 'Most time consuming section' of heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

This below query I am using for a search:

I guess this current time is not bad but still I am searching for some kind of more optimizations. Also I saw in the analyze report this nested loop and nested loop joins shows the red. It would be great if I get an idea to reduce that. I was thinking to add index for search key. It would be great if I can get more suggestions to improve this. Here I have added the explain analyze result with 3 times execution, which ran in production

Comment: If this is your most time consuming query, you're golden. 77ms is nothing, especially when your max invocations is 29.

Comment: If you sort your queries by how much time they take, there will always be something on the top of that list.  Is there a reason to care?  Is there a problem to solve?

Comment: In heroku they says this 'Queries ranking high on this list are good candidates for optimization as they tend to be both slow and high volume' so here this above query is in the 2nd position, so I am just worrying about that

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add ingredients.name or ingredients.code to an existing index or to create a new index so that more rows are filtered during ingredients index scan. 
You should also try to avoid to use fonction on column name such as LOWER(ingredients.name) to make sure the right index is used.

Comment: but we add the index with LOWER then that will be used with proper index I guess

Comment: Yes according to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/indexes-expressional.html.

Comment: Actually I am not seeing much difference for that index

Comment: Thanks. The index scan on `ingredients_company_id_index` is taking all the time, which is surprising. Can you add `BUFFERS` to the `EXPLAIN` so I can see the blocks touched and perhaps I/O statistics? Did you delete a lot of rows recently? Is the result persistend over several runs?

Comment: I didn't delete rows @LaurenzAlbe, I have ran this query 3 times in production I have added the explain details in the question, can you have look in to that?

Comment: @Developer If you move the condition from the join clause to the `WHERE` clause, you are changing the semantics of the query, effectively turning outer joins to inner joins. PostgreSQL then has many more options to optimize the query, so it becomes faster. Use outer joins only if you really need them.

Comment: thanks @LaurenzAlbe, Do you think any kind of index will help after you check that analysis result. Also can you explain where should I use the outer join to get the result effectively?

Comment: Only you can know if you need the outer join... If you are happy with the modified, faster query, use it by all means.

Comment: Currently we can't change the left join to inner join because as we need some data with the left join, so I am looking to do a pefect change in the current query so you'r saying I can use full outer join instead of the left and put the null condition in where clause? sorry It would be great if you can do some change in the above query then it will be more clear for me to understand @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: I don't think the query can be optimized. Do you actually have a problem with the run time?

Comment: "Red" in explain.depesz.com only means that that is the most expensive part of the query. It doesn't mean that there is anything wrong. Is the query too slow for you?

Comment: Yeah right @LaurenzAlbe. Actually we are checking all the queries which have the time more that 50 ms so I noticed this and looking for some kind of optimization so that is the reason I put it here, and expecting something from you experience to make it fast, thanks

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong with the execution of this query. It is not a simple query, so it takes some time.